# Getting "Access Denied" on opening publicly shared Dashboard Action

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-waf

Getting below message on page that opens up on clicking “Open in CloudWatch“ via Actions dropdown in `AWS publicly shared Dashboard.`

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>xxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RequestId>
<HostId>yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy</HostId>
</Error>
```

“Open in CloudWatch” should not present in the dropdown so that the same cannot be accessed.